# Node.js - exec shell commands with .bashrc initialized

Tags: node.js, bash

I'm writing a small utility tool for development to sync files over ssh. Normally I use ssh-agent set up in .bashrc file to connect to my dev server easily. I'd like to use exec in the script, but calling ssh-agent, every time I make a request sounds a bit inoptimal.

Is there a way I could execute the agent code once, and then have it working for all subsequent ssh requests I make? E.g. to spawn a shell process like a terminal emulator, and then use that process to execute a command, rather than invoking a new shell with each command.

The reason I want to do this, is I don't want to store the password in a config file.

Comment: Something like https://github.com/mimecuvalo/paramikojs I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one ssh process, and then execute other commands using same process. Here is an example how to use it for bash. I'm creating a new `bash` shell and execugte the command `ls -la` and `exit` you can execute other commands.

```
const cp = require("child_process")

class MyShell {
  constructor(command) {
    this._spawned = cp.spawn(command, {
      stdio: ["pipe", "pipe", "inherit"],
    })
  }
  execute(command, callback) {
    this._spawned.stdin.write(command + "\n")
    this._spawned.stdout.on("data", (chunk) => {
      if (callback) {
        callback(chunk.toString())
      }
    })
  }
}

var myShell = new MyShell("bash")
myShell.execute("ls -la", (result) => {
  console.log(result)
})
myShell.execute("exit")
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I have been looking for, I can ssh without the app even being aware there is a key.

Comment: I would add a small improvement here. In execute method, add command=command+';echo done;';  ssh and scp don't seem to output any data, but echoing something right after the command works, Otherwise the callback will not execute.